# Adding custom control tag to navigation menu

Tags: 2010, master-page, navigation

How to add div to navigation menu item? Basically, I want to add div before each list item in menu so they separate the items, I cant use paddings or margins, because if I use them submenu values from menu creates white background at sides of each dropdown menu option, or stays at same place and are misaligned with menu option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO there should be nothing you can't do with CSS.

You can fairly easily discover and override default CSS styles and take advantage of selectors to do and undo styling throughout the markup.

However, there are other approaches, in case you want to go that way:

- [UseSimpleRendering](http://blog.drisgill.com/2009/11/sp2010-branding-tip-7-using-simple.html)
- [JQuery.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this problem, instead adding new controls, I just used paddings and margins, plus, I hid iframe which created white background (needed IE specific css):

```
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
```